# GalleryView instead of getting from drawable is it possible to get from asset folder all images?

Tags: android

GalleryView instead of getting from drawable is it possible to get from asset folder all images?if it is possible?explain how?i tried by set and getbitmap..if i use that what should i need to return in getcount method?